# How does the todays Google picture control work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking at the javascript picture control on google search page and I was wondering how I could replicate it. I can see it blows up a picture on the hoverover but I cant find the code they are using in html.

Can some one help me.

Comment: This question is now completely useless. Which picture are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I just responded to a similar question @ [Jquery Image popout on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521249/jquery-image-popout-on-hover/4521364#4521364) -- my answer was a CSS3 example.

Also, see http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/x4Frn/

Comment: @frictionlesspulley Yep, I mentioned browser support in the link to the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source:

```
<div id="hplogo-..." style="background-color: rgb(153, 77, 51); position: absolute; width: 201px; height: 121px; left: -28px; top: 31px; z-index: 17;">
  <div style="overflow: hidden; top: 6px; left: 6px; position: absolute; height: 109px; width: 189px; ">
    <a href="/search?q=...">
      <img src="/logos/..." border="0" style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -110px; ">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first `<div>` positions the image and adds a background color. The second `<div>` hides the overflow to avoid that the image get's out of the box and is placed 6 pixels from the first div, which creates a border. On top of that, the image is placed, and because it is a sprite, it has some offset.

Hovering the first div will change the width and height of the first two divs and will reposition the first div.